# PHP Checking for holidays and add delivery date

Tags: php, date, foreach

I want to make a script that will check future days for holidays and based on this it will add days to delivery date. So

```
$holidays2014 = array('01.01','21.01','01.05','08.05','05.07','06.07','28.09','28.10','17.11','24.12','25.12','26.12');

$day1 = date("d.m");
$day2 = date("d.m", time() + 86400);
$day3 = date("d.m", time() + 172800);
$day4 = date("d.m", time() + 259200);
$day5 = date("d.m", time() + 345600);

foreach($holidays as $hol)
{

}
```

there is an holiday array of my country I loop trough it with foreach and check if future days are holidays BUT I am not looking for whole solution I would like to hear if it is good idea or I am doing it wrong? Making conditions is not a problem but It is long and not nice.

Comment: Store the dates in your DB and then, when showing delivery date, check how many holidays are between your normal delivery time and add the changes to the end date.

Answer (score 1):

Looping in as array is not a good idea, but as suggested by @Dainis Abols

You can save the holiday dates as a table in DB

[image]

then you can take the two dates between which you want to find the no of days as

```
 $day1 = date("Y-m-d");
 $day2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+6 month'));
```

Then you can get the no of days of holidays between these two dates as follows

```
$sql = "SELECT count(dates) as noDays FROM holidaystable WHERE dates BETWEEN '".$day1."' AND '".$day2."'";


$exe = mysql_query($sql);

$res = mysql_fetch_array($exe);



$noOfDaysHolidays = $res['noDays'];

echo $noOfDaysHolidays;
```

Comment: It is not what I wanted but it helped me anyway so thx ;)